# Reading a file in c into an array which is store its element as a struct

Tags: c

I have an assignment in C language specifically. It is about reading a text file which have the structure like this and store it to an array:

```
** (A number here to represent the chapter that relate varying from like 1 to 12 ) A Question 
:   
\# Answer 1
  
\# Answer 2 
  
\# Answer 3
  
....
```

Struct for each quiz stored to the array is :

```
typedef {  

     int group;  

     char content[255]; //content of the quiz  

     char answer[5][255];
}
```

The Answers is varying from 1 to 5 . And the file gonna have more than 100 hundreds question for each chapter. I am kinda stuck right now because I am really new for this. Hope for some way to store this huge file. Thanks for helping me !

Comment: `man realloc` ...

Comment: Huge?  Twelve chapters with a hundred questions in each chapter, with about 1.5 KiB data for each question adds up to 18 MiB.  Huge files don't start until you reach gigabytes at least.

Comment: You probably need `typedef struct Question { … } Question;` or thereabouts (you might prefer `Quiz` to `Question`, for example) to let the structure definition compile.

Comment: I mean I got stuck on transfer the question and the answer into the array because the number of answers is not consistent only have the ** and # to differentiate between them

Comment: Don't "transfer" data.  Read one character from the input stream: if it is a `*`, then read the rest of the line into `content`. If it is a backslash, read the rest of the line into the answer array.  If it is anything else, throw an error (or deal with `:` or blank lines as needed.)  Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum.
StackOverflow isn't a free coding service, but we can give you advice if you post up some more complete code.

I'm a little unclear as to you exact line format, but needless to say.

Break your problem down into manageable parts.

Your basic program structure is to:

1. Open a text file.
2. Read a line of text.
3. Parse the text to populate values in your structure.
4. If the line starts `**` its a chapter heading & question, if it starts `\#` its an answer.)
5. Return to 2 and repeat until the end of file is reached.

Things that you should look out for:

Memory allocation - start with a fixed sized array of structures (check your definition its missing a `struct` keyword) then move onto dynamic allocation once you can parse lines of text correctly.

Start with a text file that has one question and 5 answers before adding more or changing the number of answers per chapter.

Be cautious of out of bounds values e.g. if there are more than 5 answers to a question then you must ignore the extra ones.

Comment: thanks for this . Im gonna work hard for this